# Operation with Javascript with a variable from a form in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new on this site, so please don't judge me. ;)
Btw, my question is about how can i call varible(montoUti) from this form and make an operation with javascript by the moment when I select an option.

I've been reading that i can use a function called "onchange" but I'm not sure how it works.

I have this code in php that is calles FEvaluacion.php

`

```
<select class="col-lg-12" name="montoUti" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="<?php echo $montoUti?>">------</option>

<?php
 require("connect_db.php");
 $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT montoUti FROM utilidad");    
  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
  {     
  echo '<option 
  value="'.$valores[montoUti].'">'.$valores[montoUti].'</option>';    
  }
 ?>
</select>'
```

And here we have the another code in javascript called operacion.php

```
`<script>
function myFunction() 
{   
var bmontoUti = document.getElementById("montoUti").value;      

    if(prom>=60 && prom<=80)
    {
    utilidad=(prom/bmontoUti)*5;
    document.formulario.utilidad.value=utilidad;
     }
 }
 </script>'
```

However, I really hope you can help me.
Thanks 
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use `document.getElementById("montoUti").value;` you need to set an id in your `<select>` you are currently just setting a name try

```
<select class="col-lg-12" id="montoUti" name="montoUti" onchange="myFunction()">
```